# Windows Batch File CGI parse GET request

Tags: parsing, batch-file, get, cgi, html-escape-characters

I was wondering how, if possible I can parse the `QUERY_STRING` in a .bat CGI script... like so:

Request:

```
QUERY_STRING=namebox=john%20doe&passwordbox=myPasscode
```

What I want:

```
set namebox=john doe && set passwordbox=myPasscode
```

thanks all, C.

Comment: I am not understanding where you are getting the data from.

Comment: I am getting the data from a form with this tag: <FORM ACTION="/cgi-bin/process.bat" METHOD="GET">

Comment: How the query string will be transfered to the batch file? Via arguments like process.bat "amebox=john%20doe&passwordbox=myPasscode" or via a variable?

Comment: Please note that https://stackoverflow.com is not a free script/code writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (include the scripts/code you are already using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: reply to @jeb I am using Apache HTTPD server binary for windows. the query string is passed using the variable %QUERY_STRING%... I've tried numerous codes, including `set parseq=%QUERY_STRING:&= %` etc... I'm pretty good at batch, but have no idea how the FOR command works... pretty sure FOR is the answer here, but the TechNet   description of FOR is VERY CONFUSING...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for /f "tokens=1-3 delims=&%20" %a in ("%QUERY_STRING%") do set "namebox=%a %b" && set "passwordbox=%c"

Comment: Try this: for /f "tokens=1-5 delims==&%20" %a in ("%QUERY_STRING%") do set "namebox=%b %c" && set "passwordbox=%e"

Comment: `set QUERY_STRING="namebox=john%%20doe&passwordbox=myPasscode"
for /f "tokens=1-5 delims==&%20" %a in ("%QUERY_STRING%") do set "namebox=%b %c" && set "passwordbox=%e"
set
pause`

Comment: Notice doublequoetes positions, and do not double percent sign:  set "QUERY_STRING=namebox=john%20doe&passwordbox=myPasscode"

Comment: tried it that way, didn't work either. remember this is in a Batch file, not just in the command line. I keep getting: `Error: QUERY_STRINGb was not expected at this time` ??? I didn't put a b in there!!!???